# why the size of an object inherited from the NSObject is 16bytes

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, nsobject

I have a new object inherited from `NSObject`

```
Car *myCar = [[Car alloc] init];
```

This returns 16, the size of a `Car` object

```
printf("myCar object: %d\n", sizeof(*myCar));
```

plz help me to make it clear, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` in this case works like C.

As bbum said, you should not use `sizeof` on `NSObject` types (but pointers to `NSObject`s are ok). Clang forbids requesting the `sizeof` and object. The objc runtime should be your reference if you need an object's size because the actual size of an objc object is not a static (compile-time) value, it is determined at runtime.

Given these types:

```
@interface A : NSObject
@end

@interface B : A
{
    uint64_t ivar;
}
@end
```

And these messages:

```
printf("Class size is %lu\n", sizeof(Class)); // << for NSObject.isa
printf("NSObject size is %lu\n", sizeof(NSObject));
printf("A size is %lu\n", sizeof(A));
printf("B size is %lu\n", sizeof(B));
```

On 64 bit, we get:

```
Class size is 8
NSObject size is 8
A size is 8
B size is 16
```

And on 32 bit, we get:

```
Class size is 4
NSObject size is 4
A size is 4
B size is 12
```

There's a little example which shows you why sizes grow. For more detail, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) is the wikipedia page.

Comment: Note that sizeof() won't work for NSString, NSArray, and any other class that does a variable sized allocation to tack data onto the end of the instance (effectively, these classes have a char data[] variable sized ivar as the last ivar).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `sizeof()` to determine the size of an Objective-C object.  You can use `class_getInstanceSize()` instead.

**However**, the size of an instance of a class is quite thoroughly useless for many, many, reasons.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is the number of bytes that was allocated to store object of class `NSObject`.

Why do not you like it?