# Object size limit in NSArray, NSData, NSMutuableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

In `NSArray`, `NSMutuableArray`,... data types, the `addobject:` method, can I
 set the size of that to some limit?

Comment: NO. You need to make new class or category to NSArray

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to constrain the amount of elements that can be added to an NSMutableArray?

if so, then you can just check that the current count is less then your desired max prior to adding a new object:

```
if (someMutableArray.count < max) {
    [someMutableArray addObject:anObject];
};
```

Comment: 'max' can be your maximum limit

Comment: No. Not That. I am asking whether I can constrain the size of "anObject" itself?

Comment: That's going to depend a lot on what type of object you are talking about. Does it have some type of <code>size</size> property? There will have to be some meaningful definition of intrinsic "size" you can use, otherwise you'll find yourself unsuccessfully calling sizeof() which is not going to help you. [perhaps this post can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075350/why-the-size-of-an-object-inherited-from-the-nsobject-is-16bytes)